# Disabling text boxes on submit and enabling on reset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation

Using Jquery, Need to disable textbox once the textbox is submitted and
on clicking clear button, the values in textbox should be cleared and enabled.

code:

```
<table width="75%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h:outputLabel   value="Actual Card Number">
      </h:outputLabel>
     </td>
     <td>
       <h:outputLabel value="Disguised" style="font: 13px/15px Arial,sans-serif!important;">
       </h:outputLabel>

     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h:inputText id="Actualcard" styleClass="input-text-bx">

      </h:inputText>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h:inputText id="Disguisedcard" styleClass="input-text-bx">

      </h:inputText>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr class="field">
    <td>
      <h:commandButton styleClass="input-sub-btn" value="Submit">
      </h:commandButton>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <h:commandButton styleClass="input-sub-btn" value="Clear">
      </h:commandButton>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 'textbox is submitted' or 'form is submitted' ? Where  are the 'submit' and 'clear' buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do the required behavior.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("[value='Submit']").click(function(event){
//code for Submit
$(".input-text-bx").attr("disabled","disabled"); //disable all text fields.
event.preventDefault();
});


$("[value='Clear']").click(function(event){
//code for Clear
$(".input-text-bx").removeAttr("disabled"); //enable all text fields.
$(".input-text-bx").attr("value",""); //clear all text fields.
event.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply same class to all elements which you want to disable or enable

onSubmit :

```
  $('.className').attr('disabled','true');
```

onReset :

```
    $('.className').attr('disabled','false');
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to give id to your submit (e.g. btnSubmit) and clear (e.g. btnClear) buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', 'true');   //disables all textbox
    });

    $('#btnClear').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: i am not sure about "textbox is submitted"

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to disable it is to add disabled property to that element (input, textarea, select, button).for example:

```
<form action="url" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="input-field" value=".input-field">
  <input type="button" class="button-field" value=".input-field">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-button" value=".input-radio">
  <select class="select-box">
    <option value="1">One</option>
  <select class="select-box">
</form>
```

jQuery code to disable form elements and enable them back:

```
// jQuery code to disable
$('.input-field').prop('disabled', true);
$('.button-field').prop('disabled', true);
$('.radio-button').prop('disabled', true);
$('.select-box').prop('disabled', true);

// To enable an element you need to either
// remove the disabled attribute or set it to "false"
// For jQuery versions earlier than 1.6, replace .prop() with .attr()
$('.input-field').prop('disabled', false);
$('.button-field').removeAttr('disabled');
$('.radio-button').prop('disabled', null);
$('.select-box').prop('disabled', false);
```